# GET Request with AFHttpRequestOperationManager not working on 3G

Tags: ios, objective-c, httprequest

GET Request with AFHttpRequestOperationManager not working on 3G works only on wifi

here is my code

it works correctly on wifi or when request data was cashed 
I find a question put for POST request

```
-(void)getHomeworksWithChildId:(double)childId AndIsFromRecycleBin:(NSNumber*) isFromRecyclebin
{
    if (([isFromRecyclebin isEqualToNumber:@1])) {
        isFromRecyclebin = @0;
    }
    else
        isFromRecyclebin = @1;

    NSString *reportsUrl  = [self getFullURLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:homeworks_URL,self.currentUser.iDProperty,childId,isFromRecyclebin]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];
    [manager GET:reportsUrl parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         if ([(NSArray*)responseObject count]>0)
         {

             NSMutableArray *allPictures = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
             for (int i=0; i<[(NSArray*)responseObject count]; i++) {
                 Report *report = [[Report alloc]initWithDictionary:[responseObject objectAtIndex:i]];
                 [allPictures addObject:report];
             }
             NSDictionary *userInfo= [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:@[allPictures,@0] forKeys:@[@"reports",@"digital"]];
             NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
             [defaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"catname"];
             [defaults synchronize];
             [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:NSLocalizedString(@"", @"")];
             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:REPORTS_RECIEVED_NOTIFICATION object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
         }
         else
             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:REPORTS_RECIEVED_NOTIFICATION object:nil userInfo:nil];
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:REPORTS_RECIEVED_NOTIFICATION object:nil userInfo:nil];
         [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:error.localizedDescription];
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
}
```

Comment: Did you enable access to 3G network for your app?

Comment: "Not working". Do you hit error? How do you know it's not working?

Comment: [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:error.localizedDescription];
it shows progress of error

Comment: And what's the `error.localizedDescription`?

Comment: coulden't connect to the server!